# Custom tab completion in R function

Tags: r, autocomplete

I am currently writing a function which only accepts certain inputs (in the example only "a" and "b"). For all other inputs the function will return an error.

```
test <- function(x) {
  allowedX <- c("a","b")
  if(x %in% allowedX) print("Good choice!")
  else stop("wrong input!")
}
```

To help users of the function I would like to supply the allowed values for x (stored in *allowedX*) using the tab completion feature in R and replace the default file name completion which is typically applied after a quote. So pressing TAB should give something like:

```
test(x="<TAB>
a b
```

However, I couldn't find a solution so far how to map the vector *allowedX* to the tab completion in R. Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should see `match.arg`...The <TAB> (\t) is not clear.

Comment: What I mean with <TAB> is that typically, if you start typing a command in R and you press the tabulator button (<TAB>) on your keyboard you get a list of possible options to complete your command. For instance typing `read.csv` and tapping <TAB> twice will give you `read.csv read.csv2` as the two options to complete your command. If you do the same for a started quote R will show you a list of files in your current directory. What I am trying to do is that in my case one should get the two options `a b` shown when tapping <TAB> after opening the quote for x `test(x="<TAB>`.

Comment: Not "typically" -- just in whatever GUI or command interface you happen to be using.   You might possibly be able to do something like `test <- function() {x <- readline("input, please") ; if(grep(x, some_magic_pattern,allowedX) ) do_something } ` .  But... you seem to be trying to build a GUI inside your function.  I'd recommend doing the whole thing via TclTK, which can be called from R.

Comment: As far as I understand the tab completion in R is independent of the used GUI. I found some information about that in the R documentation: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/rcompgen.html However, it does not tell me how to customize it for the use in own functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
test <- function() {
  allowedX <- c("a","b")
  x = readline('Please enter your choice of parameters (either "a" or "b"): ')
  if(x %in% allowedX) print("Good choice!")
  else stop("wrong input!")
}
```